# В знании — сила

Tags: синтаксис

Какая в этом предложении грамматическая основа и каков вид этого предложения?

Answer (score 3):

***В знании — сила.***

Это двусоставное предложение эллиптического вида (обстоятельство — подлежащее)

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с **отсутствующим сказуемым**): За ночным окном — туман (Бл.); Олимпийский огонь — на нашей земле! (Газ.);  И затем — минутная тишина; Арбузов и дынь — горы; ответ -— полное молчание;